# Qt Creator help: Font size is too small

Tags: qt, ide, qt-creator

I am using Qt Creator 3.3.0 on Gentoo linux.
Qt docs are displayed in help mode. The main text there is too small to read. Font size settings in Qt Creator settings changes size of headers and images only. So does zooming with mouse wheel.
How can I set size of text? How can I enable zooming with mouse wheel?

Comment: So Ctrl + mouse wheel doesn't work?

Comment: Well, it works, but changes only the size of headers and images, not the size of text.

Answer (score 1):

Qt Creator uses QWebView to display help. Zooming with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>mouse wheel</kbd> should be working. This is Qt Creator help plugin source:

```
void QtWebKitHelpWidget::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event)
{
    if (event->modifiers()& Qt::ControlModifier) {
        event->accept();
        event->delta() > 0 ? scaleUp() : scaleDown();
    } else {
        QWebView::wheelEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Apparently your Qt build on Gentoo is compiled with some features being disabled. Either use the official SDK or rebuild Qt with `./configure -webkit`, paying attention that QtWebKit builds fine.

Comment: Mouse wheel changes only the size of headers and images, not the size of text.

Comment: Like I said, the problem is in your Qt libraries.

Comment: It looks like this problem still exists on macOS, using the release libs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem still persists even though I installed newest QtCreator 4.10.2 right from official online installer. And if you just wonder how the problem looks like, here is a snap.
[image]

Ctrl+Scroll changes only header font which is perfectly readable on my screen. Rest of text can't be changed and it looks unreadable. Is there any workaround? I don't believe only 5 people who upvoted use reference in qt on ubuntu.